# How to use "case when" in Hadoop pig?

Tags: apache-pig

what is the correct pig language for this pig-sql pseudocode?
`data = foreach data generate case when column1 is null then -1 else column2 end as new_column;`
I google for case when in hadoop pig but there is none. So what is the alternative way to do this in pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using CASE WHEN is:

```
new_data = FOREACH data GENERATE 
    *,
    (CASE 
        WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN -1
        ELSE column2
    END) AS new_column;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to use a bincond expression, something like:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
    *,
    (column1 IS NULL ? -1 : column2) AS new_column
    ;
```

Pig does have a WHEN CASE function which can be used instead of chaining together binconds which is a bit messy. You can read more under Arithmetic Operators and More here: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html